# FMDB: Database is locked when updating

Tags: ios, fmdb

I'm using `FMDB` and I'm using `FMDatabase` when I want to return some value and `FMDatabaseQueue` when I don't need to return any value.
When I add to database and I use the `FMDatabaseQueue` I've no errors (except when I create a new database at the beginning when I'm deleting the database and then create [no database to delete so it creates a new one]).
The problem is when I'm updating my `database` with the same `FMDatabaseQueue` I've an error:

> Unknown error finalizing or resetting statement (5: database is
>   locked)
>
> DB Query: UPDATE traps_table SET dist=34721.853417,
>   dist_to_close_point=35734.768293 WHERE _id=10

When I try the query on the database file itself I get no errors and all went great.

Code below:

```
- (void)updateTrapInDatabase:(FMDatabase*)db distance:(double)distance trapID:(int)trapID distanceToClosePoint:(double)distanceToClosePoint
{
    NSString *statment = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE %@ SET %@=?, %@=? WHERE %@=?", TRAP_TABLE, DISTANCE, DISTANCE_TO_CLOSE_POINT, ID];
    BOOL update = [db executeUpdate:statment, @(distance), @(distanceToClosePoint), @(trapID)];
    NSLog(@"Update trapID: %i, success: %@", trapID, update?@"YES":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"NO: %@", [db lastErrorMessage]]);
}
```

The code where the function referenced from:

```
- (void)UpdateDistanceToTrap_currentLocation:(CLLocation*)currentLocation old_location:(CLLocation*)old_location theAzimuth:(double)theAzimuth theSpeed:(double)theSpeed
{
    NSLog(@"UpdateDistanceToTrap()");

    __block double latColumn, lonColumn, idColumn, closePointLatColumn, closePointLonColumn, alarmDistanceColumn;
    __block int _id = -1, alarmDistance = -1;
    __block double distance;
    __block CLLocation *trap_location = nil;

    __block NSString *sqlStatment = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM %@", TRAP_TABLE];

    FMResultSet *query = [trapsDB.db executeQuery:sqlStatment];

    if ([query next]) {
        latColumn = [query doubleForColumn:LAT];
        lonColumn = [query doubleForColumn:LON];
        closePointLatColumn = [query doubleForColumn:CLOSE_POINT_LAT];
        closePointLonColumn = [query doubleForColumn:CLOSE_POINT_LON];
        idColumn = [query intForColumn:@"_id"];
        alarmDistanceColumn = [query intForColumn:ALARMDISTANCE];

        do {
            _id = [query intForColumn:@"_id"];
            alarmDistance = [query intForColumn:ALARMDISTANCE];

            if ([old_location distanceFromLocation:currentLocation] > kDISTANCE_THRESHOLD_FOR_CHECK_LOCATIONS) {
                trap_location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[query doubleForColumn:LAT]
                                                           longitude:[query doubleForColumn:LON]];

                distance = [trap_location distanceFromLocation:currentLocation];

                if (distance < alarmDistance + [ref integerForKey:@"DISTANCE_OFFSET"]) {
                    [trapsDB enterOrOutFromArea_operation:kENTER andTrapID:_id];

                    [self startSaveOnMyLocations:currentLocation.coordinate.latitude
                                             lon:currentLocation.coordinate.longitude
                                            time:CreateDate()
                                           speed:theSpeed
                                         azimuth:theAzimuth
                                          trapID:_id];
                }
                else {
                    if ([trapsDB isEnterToArea_trapID:_id] == kENTER) {
                        [self startPostXml:_id];
                        [trapsDB enterOrOutFromArea_operation:kOUT andTrapID:_id];
                    }
                }
            }
            if ([query doubleForColumn:CLOSE_POINT_LAT] != 0.0 || [query doubleForColumn:CLOSE_POINT_LAT] != 0) {
                trap_location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[query doubleForColumn:CLOSE_POINT_LAT]
                                                           longitude:[query doubleForColumn:CLOSE_POINT_LON]];

                double distanceToClosePoint = [trap_location distanceFromLocation:currentLocation];

                trap_location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[query doubleForColumn:LAT]
                                                           longitude:[query doubleForColumn:LON]];

                distance = [trap_location distanceFromLocation:currentLocation];

                [trapsDB updateTrapInDatabase:trapsDB.db distance:distance trapID:_id distanceToClosePoint:distanceToClosePoint];
            }
            else {
                trap_location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[query doubleForColumn:LAT]
                                                           longitude:[query doubleForColumn:LON]];

                distance = [trap_location distanceFromLocation:currentLocation];

                [trapsDB updateTrapInDatabase:trapsDB.db distance:distance trapID:_id distanceToClosePoint:distance];
            }
        } while ([query next]);
    }
}
```

Whats wrong with my code?

**EDIT:**

TrapService.mm:

```
- (void)UpdateDistanceToTrap_currentLocation:(CLLocation*)currentLocation old_location:(CLLocation*)old_location theAzimuth:(double)theAzimuth theSpeed:(double)theSpeed;

#define trapsDB     ([SQLiteHandler sharedDatabase])
```

SQLiteHandler.m:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) FMDatabase *db;

- (void)updateTrapInDatabase:(FMDatabase *)db distance:(double)distance trapID:(int)trapID distanceToClosePoint:(double)distanceToClosePoint;
```

**EDIT-2:**
Updated my fixed code.

Comment: How can I return a object from 'FMDatabaseQueue' using block? I can give up this way on 'FMDatabase'.

Comment: I'm unclear about what you mean by "I can give up this way on `FMDatabase`", but in answer to your question, you can use `__block` qualifier on variable defined outside of the block. That allows the block to update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are inside a `inDatabase` call, iterating through a `SELECT` statement and you then attempt to do another `inDatabase` call. If you're going to do that, you probably want to pass the `FMDatabase` as a parameter to the method, and not call `inDatabase` again:

```
- (void)updateTrapInDatabase:(FMDatabase *)db distance:(double)distance trapID:(int)trapID distanceToClosePoint:(double)distanceToClosePoint
{
    NSString *sqlStatment = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE %@ SET %@=?, %@=? WHERE %@=?", TRAP_TABLE, DISTANCE, DISTANCE_TO_CLOSE_POINT, ID];

    BOOL update = [db executeUpdate:sqlStatment, @(distance), @(distanceTpClosePoint), @(trapID)];
    NSLog(@"Update trapID: %i, success: %@", trapID, update?@"YES":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"NO: %@", [db lastErrorMessage]]);
}
```

and replacing your call to:

```
[trapsDB updateTrapDistance:distance andTrapID:_id andDistanceToClosePoint:distanceToClosePoint];
```

with:

```
[trapsDB updateTrapInDatabase:db distance:distance trapID:_id distanceToClosePoint:distanceToClosePoint];
```

(As an aside, it's generally prudent to use `?` placeholders in your SQL (avoids precision related problems with `float` variables, avoids SQL injection problems and quoting problems with `NSString` variables), so I also tweaked the SQL above. Also, if a SQL statement fails, I always log `lastErrorMessage`, otherwise I'm just guessing why the SQL failed. Use or disregard these unrelated tweaks as you see fit.)

But the main point is that one should never call `inDatabase` while already in an `inDatabase`. What's curious, though, is that calling `inDatabase` while already in an `inDatabase` generally causes a deadlock, not a "database is locked" error. Frankly, the entire purpose of `FMDatabaseQueue` is to mediate database requests from different threads so that a database will never be busy. The only time you would generally receive "database is locked" error is if you had more than one `FMDatabaseQueue` or `FMDatabase` object. Your app should only have one database object open at any given time.

Comment: As a final aside, when updating a bunch of records, you may want to use `inTransaction` rather than `inDatabase`. Using SQLite transactions can have significant impact on performance. I also would personally avoid updating a table that I'm currently iterating through altogether, saving the updates in an array, and performing the updates later.

Comment: I updated my question. I updated my code as you wrote and I still get: "Unknown error calling sqlite3_step (5: database is locked) eu
2014-01-19 16:54:36.461 Cellular Radar[966:60b] DB Query: UPDATE traps_table SET dist=?, dist_to_close_point=? WHERE _id=?
2014-01-19 16:54:36.462 Cellular Radar[966:60b] Unknown error finalizing or resetting statement (5: database is locked)
2014-01-19 16:54:36.465 Cellular Radar[966:60b] DB Query: UPDATE traps_table SET dist=?, dist_to_close_point=? WHERE _id=?
2014-01-19 16:54:36.467 Cellular Radar[966:60b] Update trapID: 1, success: NO: database is locked".

Comment: @IdanMoshe That would suggest that you have another `FMDatabase` or `FMDatabaseQueue` instance out there that has the database open already. Also, while I don't think this would cause the problem you describe, you might not want to try to UPDATE your table while you still have the SELECT statement open on that table. You're trying to read and write to the same table at the same time. In my tests it works, but it strikes me as something that could theoretically result in the error you describe. But a separate `FMDatabaseQueue` or `FMDatabase` object is far more likely.

Comment: OK, I should have avoid 'FMDatabaseQueue', I removed it and now it works, thanks!

Comment: @IdanMoshe Excellent. By the way, I don't think the problem is `FMDatabaseQueue`, _per se_, but rather the interplay between this queue object and other objects that you might have had. I just don't want you to lose your faith with `FMDatabaseQueue`. If you do multi-threaded programming, it will save you a lot of time and effort in coordinating database interaction between threads. But at least you solved your immediate problem!

Answer (score 1):

For me,close  `FMResultSet` solved my problem,for example:

```
- (BOOL)checkKeepAccounts {
    NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM %@ where checked is 1", kGoodsListTable];
    FMResultSet *s = [self.database executeQuery:sql];
    int count = 0;
    if ([s next]) {
        count = [s intForColumnIndex:0];
    }
    **// This is the key**
    [s close];
    return count == 0;
}
```

Not sure if this helpful to you, but I think it's worth sharing.